# How to automatically copy and rename files from one GitHub folder to another

Tags: github, arduino, github-actions

I am trying to find a way to keep 2 IDE versions of a project in the same repository. I am using PlatformIO to create an Arduino project. But non-Programmers need to be able to use the Arduino IDE to upload the sketch to their device. So I would have 2 folders in the repository, a "Program" folder with the PlatformIO formatted version and a "Program_Arduino_IDE" folder both in the root. The "Program/src" subfolder holds the code. I want to copy all those files to the "Program_Arduino_IDE/Program" folder and rename the Program.cpp to Program.ino in that folder whenever a merge is made from our development branch to our master branch of the "Program" Folder.

I have tried reading about githooks and github actions to see if they can help. I want this done on GitHub, not on my local development machine. I know both folders are in the same repository, so I'm not sure about any issues related to the fact that merging from development to master is a repository wide function, not specifically a folder function. So I could merge changes from a "docs" folder from develop to master that would not make any changes to any files in the "Programs" folder. I am new to GitHub having only a bit of Subversion experience.

Comment: Why commit both project versions? Just generate the Arduino project from the PlatformIO project with a shell script or during build.

Comment: That may work. The only issue is that this requires each contributor to know how to do this. Otherwise, someone is going to have to be responsible for updating the Arduino folder to have the necessary files with each PR for a production version for people who are just wanting to upload to a board.